# Should I toss my MSI z590 motherboard and start over?

Tags: processor, motherboard

Will my MSI MPG Z590 10th/11th gen Gaming Carbon wifi motherboard be outdated soon? Using for UE5 and game programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your CPU. If you have a high end 11th gen it won't be obsolete for those use cases probably until the next console refresh. If not it will probably last as long as you don't find it too slow. And if it becomes obsolete you can still repurpose it as a rendering/compiling server.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I got a good deal on the motherboard lol so that's a big reason I bought it. I was mainly worried about the cpu than anything. It's a solid board. I start my gamedev BS soon

Answer (score 0):

At its core the z590 chipset with a good 11th gen chip is more than enough to do whatever you want to do.

However since you are building a new pc rather than deciding to keep an existing one. It all depends on what kind of deals you can find.

The main thing to consider when looking around is that an intel 13400(or f) is about as fast as an intel 11700k. On the AMD side that is roughly a 7600, or a 5800x.

So if you go out looking for parts, make sure that the cost is the same or less than that of a newer setup with an added motherboard, and you should be alright.